# Config for MySQL max_allowed_packet is not getting picked up (Mac OSX)

Tags: mysql, macos

I can't seem to get MySQL to change the global value of `max_allowed_packet` no matter where i change it.

In `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/.my.cnf`, I have:

```
...
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port            = 3306
socket          = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 32M
...
```

In ~/.my.cnf, I have:

```
[client]
socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock
user=rc
password=shop
# database=application_data

[mysql]
prompt='MYSQL \u@\h:\d > '
# wait_timeout = 576000

[mysqld] 
socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock
max_allowed_packet=64M

[mysqldump]
```

I have different values for `max_allowed_packet` in the two cnf files to see if one supersedes the other. However, neither config is being used. When I check in MySQL to see the value in use, I get:

```
MYSQL vicinio@localhost:(none) > SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+---------+
| Variable_name      | Value   |
+--------------------+---------+
| max_allowed_packet | 1048576 |
+--------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In my System Preferences, I can restart MySQL Server using a preference pane; I am pretty sure that pref pane is using the `/Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM` script, and I can see in that script that the location it is using for mysql server is the same place I am changing configs:

```
# The path to the mysql.server init script. The official MySQL
# Mac OS X packages are being installed into /usr/local/mysql.
SCRIPT="/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server"
```

Any thoughts?

ETA: One additional note, I can change the global value in MySQL as a user, and that fixes the immediate problem, but every time the Mysql server is restarted the problem will recur. Not to mention I'd really like to understand why my configs aren't having the desired effect.

I have read various other q's on SO as well as googling but haven't found anything on point.

Comment: For those that down-vote, you might find placement or types of questions irritating, but random down-voting without a reason is just plain rude, and helps no one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be helpful: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45087/max-allowed-packet-in-mysql

Be sure to read that first comment closely. It has a couple of nuanced points for both the files and the settings in the database itself.